Aggregation - Lists
I have two nodes: Journal, Article
with the following structures: (Journal{name}) , (Article{date, title})
A journal can be linked to one or more articles by the following relationship:
(:Journal)-[:HAS_ARTICLE]->(:Article)
I am unable to write a query that gives me:

Name of the distinct journal
Title of the latest article of the parent journal

The results should be something like:
[
{journal: journal.name, latest_news: article.title},
...
]
Could you help me with this query and give me a link to elaborate on my lack of knowledge about it?
EDIT1
As per Håkan Löfqvist response, the query gives me the following results:
[{journal:"journal0", latest_news:"title1"}, {journal:"journal0",latest_news:"title2"}, {journal:"journal0", latest_news:"title3"}]

What I want is that every journal appear only one time in the lists
[{journal:"journal1", latest_news:"title"}, {journal:"journal2",latest_news:"title"}, {journal:"journal3", latest_news:"title"}]

Where journal1 != journal2 != journal3
EDIT
I copied and pasted the question (as it is) in Gemini and he provided me the desired results:
MATCH (j:Journal)-[:HAS_ARTICLE]->(a:Article)
WITH j.name AS journal, MAX(a.date) AS latestDate
MATCH (j:Journal)-[:HAS_ARTICLE]->(a:Article)
WHERE a.date = latestDate
RETURN {journal: journal, latest_news: a.title} AS result

Thank you

To show each Journal once, start with a MATCH clause that fetches each journal. To then find the latest Article for each Journal, use a CALL subquery:
MATCH (journal:Journal)
CALL {
  WITH journal
  MATCH (journal)-[:HAS_ARTICLE]->(a:Article)
  RETURN a AS latestArticle ORDER BY a.date DESC LIMIT 1
}
RETURN journal, latestArticle

Because the subquery returns only one record, the latest article, the number of rows per journal remains at one.

In line 3; where does j comes from ?

Sorry, it was just a typo. It should have been journal. Fixed.

If you want to retrieve the latest article for each journal, you can use collect { sub query } + take first element in list with [0] like this:
match (j:Journal)-[:HAS_ARTICLE]->(a:Article)
with j, collect { 
        // Sub query
        match  (j)-[:HAS_ARTICLE]->(a:Article) 
        return a 
        order by a.date desc limit 1 // Sort and return only latest article
    }[0] as latest_article
limit 10  // Limit number of journals retrived 
return collect({journal: j.name, latest_news: latest_article.title}) // Return list of dictionaries


Thank you very much!!! Is there any way to retrieve distinct journals? Like each journal appears only once in the list?

You can just do this:
MATCH (j:Journal)-[:HAS_ARTICLE]->(a:Article)
WITH j.name AS journal, a.title AS title
ORDER BY a.date DESC
RETURN journal, COLLECT(title)[0] AS latest_news

Or, to be more efficient, use apoc.agg.first(title) instead of COLLECT(title)[0]:
MATCH (j:Journal)-[:HAS_ARTICLE]->(a:Article)
WITH j.name AS journal, a.title AS title
ORDER BY a.date DESC
RETURN journal, apoc.agg.first(title) AS latest_news

